# Función agregar en laravel agrega doble en mi detalle

Tags: php, html, laravel

Este es mi código estoy trabajando con laravel 7 y resulta que el código funciona el problema es que al agregar una asignatura en el detalle me agrega 2 veces cuando debería de agregar solo una vez es. No se si el error estaría en el if o si ese error estaría ocasionando otra cosa.
Ese es el diseño en HTML es un pequeña tabla la cual contiene un select de asignaturas con el botón de agregar lo que ocurre es que cada vez que selecciono una asignatura y presiono el botón de agregar carga 2 veces la asignatura seleccionada.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-head">
                    <h4 class="text-center">Agregar Asignaturas</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="row card-body">
                    <div class="col-col-xl-22">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            {!! Form::select('asignatura_id', $asignaturas , $matriculacion->asignatura_id, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'asignaturas']) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto my-1">
                                <button onclick="agregar()" type="button" id="btn_agregar" class="btn btn-success float-right">Agregar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>       
                </div>

                <table id="detalles" class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Descripción</th>
                            <th>Eliminar</th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody id="detalles">

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@section('js')
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_agregar').click(function() {
        agregar();
    });
});

var cont = 0;

var table = document.getElementById("detalles");

function agregar() {
    asignatura_id = $("#asignaturas").val();
    descripcion = $("#asignaturas option:selected").text();

    if (descripcion != "") {
        var fila = '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont + '"><td><input type="hidden" name="asignatura_id[]" value="' + asignatura_id + '">' +
        descripcion + '</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar(' + cont +');"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td></tr>';
        cont++;
        $('#detalles').append(fila);
    } else{
        alert('Error');
    }
}

function eliminar(index) {
    $("#fila" + index).remove();
}

</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Podrías publicar el código HTML sobre el que estás trabajando? Lo que pasa es que te agrega de a 2 filas?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la publicación. Correcto cada vez que presiono el botón agregar agrega de a 2.

Comment: tienes 2 eventos... uno desde el html y otro desde javascript... :V

Comment: No entendí a que te referías con eventos, pero ahora que solucione el error te entiendo. Tuve que borrar el agregar(); que esta en el javascript el que trabaja con el id del botón. Ahora funciona a la perfección... Gracias :v